# neo4j cypher Query Invalid query Node[2131764] not found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

while running the following simple query 
`START root=node(*) 
where has ( root.ico_type ) AND root.ico_type = "PID"
RETURN count(*)`

i am getting the following error

Invalid query

Node[2131764] not found.

Comment: which version of Neo4j?

Comment: version for Neo4j : 1.8.3